# Can I / should I import an old cacert.pem?

Tags: backup, ssl, home, certificates

In my user directory on an older Linux installation, I have a `cacert.pem` file. I know it holds some sort CA certificates for use with SSL. But - in my newer user directory, I don't have such a file.

My questions:

1. Should I try to import the contents of this `cacert.pem` file?
2. If so, how (and into what) do I actually import it - on a Devuan Chimaera GNU/Linux system (or Debian 11 Bullseye)?

Comment: What problem you are trying to solve, i.e. why do you think you need to import this fle?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I'm about to delete this old folder, and I'm wondering whether there might be important certificates - if that's even possible - I might be throwing away.

Comment: Maybe checking for their expiration date might solve this: `openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in certficate.pem`.

Comment: @FelixJN: So, it's a single date... is that the minimum expiration date for certificates in the file, or the maximum?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I try to import the contents of this `cacert.pem` file?

Quite probably not. SSL certificates tend to expire; so regardless of how you got them originally, they may well be expired.

Check this! ... by running:

```
openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in cacert.pem
```

You should get a `notAfter` line as a result. When that date passes, the contents of the file should (?) be out-of-date. Example:

```
notAfter=Aug 22 16:41:51 2018 GMT
```

... in which case you can delete this file.

---

This answer is really due to @FelixJN. Thanks! :-)